# efficient way to split on punctuation without inserting a void token if sentence ends with a punctuation mark

Tags: python, regex, split

I need to split sentences on punctuation marks in python.

This command works nearly fine:

```
re.split('\W+', line.lower().strip(), flags=re.UNICODE)
```

The problem is that, if the last character of the sentence is a punctuation mark, the last token is a void token.

How can I avoid that?

I would like a solution that allows me not to insert a void token. I cannot afford to cancel it afterwards: in my case efficiency is an issue since I need to run this command over very large corpora of texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to split by non-word (`\W+`) characters, you can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with `\w+`:

```
>>> line = 'Hello world!'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', line.lower(), flags=re.UNICODE)
['hello', 'world']
# `.strip()` was remove because `\w+` does not match whitespaces.
```

SIDE NOTE: You'd better to use [`r'raw string literals'`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) to avoid backslashes to be used as escape sequences.

---

Alternative: Pass the string without trailing non-word chracters to the `re.split`:

```
>>> re.split(r'\W+', re.sub(r'\W+$', '', line.lower().strip()), flags=re.UNICODE)
['hello', 'world']
```

NOTE: You may also strip leading non-word characters. To handle both sides, use `^\W+|\W+$` pattern.